# Search array for at least 1 match and return true

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to test my JSON response to ensure at least 1 object contains a value of isKey:true at which point a global variable of hasKey is set to true.

I believe the SOME method would help in this situation but it seems to only test on a local level so if I console.log I get: true,false, true,true... etc

I just want a definitive true or false against the whole model.

Below you can see the basis of a working function, but I don't believe it is efficient so any advice is appreciated in improving this.

```
 checkKeys() {

    let checkTest: boolean = false;

    this.modalData.columnPermissions.some(function (item) {

      if (item.isKey) {
        checkTest = true;
      }
    });

    this.modalData.hasKey = checkTest;

  }
```

Comment: Read [`Array​.prototype​.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the result of `some` directly.

```
checkKeys() {
    this.modalData.hasKey = this.modalData.columnPermissions.some(function (item) {
        return item.isKey;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right function, you're just using it wrong.

```
this.modalData.hasKey = this.modalData.columnPermissions.some(function (item) {
  return item.isKey;
});
```

The 'some' function takes the return value and STOPS RUNNING as soon as one is true.

The 'every' function takes the return value and stops running as soon as one is false.